# Get Camera Position and Rotation using Aruco Markers

Tags: python, opencv, camera, aruco

I used the function `cv.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers()` to get `rvec` and `tvec`.
Using these two vectors how can I get the camera pose relative to the Aruco Marker?

```py
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL)
    parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 

    if np.all(ids != None):
        # POSE ESTIMATION
        rvec, tvec,_ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[0], 0.1, mtx, dist)
```

Answer (score 5):

`rvec` is the rotation of the marker relative to the camera frame. You can convert `rvec` to a rotation matrix using the built-in [Rodrigues function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues). Then get the inverse of this matrix (this is a rotation matrix, so the inverse is the transpose of the matrix). This is the rotation of the camera with respect to the marker.

Magnitude of the `tvec` is not affected by the rotation. If you need to consider the direction of the camera relative to the marker, just take the negative of `tvec`.